# How to execute multiple tests at the same time with jBehave?

Tags: jbehave

I have some tests created with jBehave and WebDriver.

When I execute them via Maven, the execution is secuencially:

TEST 1

- Open navigator
- Execute all the steps of the first story
- Close navigator

TEST 2

- Open navigator
- Execute all the steps of the second story
- Close navigator

...

I'm interested in execute the tests simultaneously. According the documentation, this is possible.

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/multi-threading.html

I've tried adding the notation to the  "Stories" class, and also executed the mvn command with the threads=5, but doesn't work.

```
    @UsingEmbedder(threads=5)
    public class EtsyDotComStories extends JUnitStories {

    ...
    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(), asList("**/*.story"), null);

    }

        }


 mvn clean install -s settings.xml -Pjava-spring,codehaus,threads=5
```

Is it possible to execute multiple tests simultaneously?

EDIT:

Added the maven execution part:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>embeddable-stories</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*Stories.java</include>
              </includes>
              <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
              <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
              <threads>5</threads>
              <executorsClass>org.jbehave.core.embedder.executors.SameThreadExecutors</executorsClass>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Could you please also share part of your pom, to see how you launch JBehave? Does the EtsyDotcomStories contain more configuration than what you posted?

Comment: @AndreasEK Added the part of pom that is executed. If you need more information let me know. Thanks. EtsyDotcomStories doesn't have more notations but there is a lot of code inside. If you need, I can try to add in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question could contain a little more detail, but I assume that you are using run-stories-as-embeddables goal. You basically have two options:

1. When using the run-stories-as-embeddables goal, set the property "threads" to the goal. Extending the example from the [Maven Gaols documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html):

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
       <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>[version]</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
               <phase>integration-test</phase>
               <configuration>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**/*Stories.java</include>
                   </includes>
                   <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
                   <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
                   <treads>5</threads>
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                   <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Use the run-stories-with-annotated-embedder maven goal, which should respect the Annotation

Also, the two scenarios that you describe above have to be in **two seperate** stories. Mutli-threading only happens on story-level. Scenarios inside the same story are not executed multi-threaded.

Comment: Yes I'm using run-stories-with-annotated-embedder goal. Only for clarification, what means "two seperate stories". I have only one stories class (EtsyDotComStories) and this calls all the stories. Every stories is in a different story file. It's correct?

Comment: Yes, I meant storys as in story files. All scenarios in one story (file) will be executed on one thread.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring JUnit test runner `.useThreads(20)`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    ...
})
public class Stories extends JUnitStories {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        configuredEmbedder()
                .embedderControls()
                ...
                .useThreads(20)
                .useStoryTimeouts(Integer.toString(maxIfDebugOr(1800)));
    }
...
```